# ASP.NET MVC jQGrid client side and server side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid-asp.net

I cant find any examples how to do client side validation with MVC jQGrid.
For client side I can see that i need to assign the column property EditClientSideValidators

`public List<JQGridEditClientSideValidator> EditClientSideValidators { get; set; }`

But i cant understand how to assign validation to that.

But how to do server validation it is also a question

UPDATE

I think i found something client side validation http://www.trirand.net/aspnetmvc/grid/editclientsidevalidation

Answer (score 0):

If you grabbed up the license that includes support you can ask the developer... otherwise, the link you showed has the documentation... the grid needs to request the validators when it gets the data, like so:

```
public void SetUpGrid_EditClientSideValidation(JQGrid grid)
{
    // Setting the DataUrl to an action (method) in the controller is required.
    // This action will return the data needed by the grid.
    // EditUrl will point to the editing action
    grid.DataUrl = Url.Action("EditClientSideValidation_DataRequested");
    grid.EditUrl = Url.Action("EditClientSideValidation_EditRow");

    var integerColumn = grid.Columns.Find(c => c.DataField == "Integer");
    integerColumn.EditClientSideValidators.Add(new RequiredValidator());
    integerColumn.EditClientSideValidators.Add(new MinValueValidator { MinValue = 10 });
    integerColumn.EditClientSideValidators.Add(new MaxValueValidator { MaxValue = 100 });

    var numberColumn = grid.Columns.Find(c => c.DataField == "Number");
    numberColumn.EditClientSideValidators.Add(new RequiredValidator());
    numberColumn.EditClientSideValidators.Add(new MinValueValidator { MinValue = 0.1 });
    numberColumn.EditClientSideValidators.Add(new MaxValueValidator { MaxValue = 100.1 });

    var emailColumn = grid.Columns.Find(c => c.DataField == "Email");
    emailColumn.EditClientSideValidators.Add(new RequiredValidator());
    emailColumn.EditClientSideValidators.Add(new EmailValidator());

    var linkColumn = grid.Columns.Find(c => c.DataField == "Link");
    linkColumn.EditClientSideValidators.Add(new RequiredValidator());
    linkColumn.EditClientSideValidators.Add(new UrlValidator());

    var customColumn = grid.Columns.Find(c => c.DataField == "Custom");
    customColumn.EditClientSideValidators.Add(new Trirand.Web.Mvc.CustomValidator { ValidationFunction = "validateCustomField" });
    }

// This method is called when the grid requests data. You can choose any method to call
// by setting the JQGrid.DataUrl property
public JsonResult EditClientSideValidation_DataRequested()
{
    // Get both the grid Model
    // The data model in our case is an autogenerated linq2sql database based on Northwind.
    var gridModel = new EditValidationModel();
    SetUpGrid_EditClientSideValidation(gridModel.ValidatedGrid);

    // return the result of the DataBind method, passing the datasource as a parameter
    // jqGrid for ASP.NET MVC automatically takes care of paging, sorting, filtering/searching, etc
    List employees = GetClientValidatedEmployeeData();
    return gridModel.ValidatedGrid.DataBind(employees.AsQueryable());
}
```